# Magento pagamento digital error

Tags: magento

I'm trying to install Pagamento Digital module in my Magento 1.6.2.0 but there are some error log that I can't figure out what to do...

I've been searching for 3 days until now and if someone could light my path would be blessed !!!

Module URL: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/buscape-pagamento-digital-4971.html

Error Log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:87:"Mage registry key "_singleton/pagamentodigital/source_specificcountries" already exists";i:1;s:1647:"

#0 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/Mage.php(192): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...') #1 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/Mage.php(446): Mage::register('_singleton/paga...', false) 
#2 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(407): Mage::getSingleton('pagamentodigita...') 
#3 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(210): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)) 
#4 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm() 
#5 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(102): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm() 
#6 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction() 
#7 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit') 
#8 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) 
#9 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
#10 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#11 /home/wwwmirom/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store') 
#12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:99:"/~wwwmirom/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/payment/key/e94bbab2478ea8f5cf8dc57068597e1b/";s:11:"script_name";s:20:"/~wwwmirom/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're dealing with a hacked/modified core.  This extension is attempting to use the `getSingleton` method to instantiate a class.  If you look at an unmodified core

```
public static function getSingleton($modelClass='', array $arguments=array())
{
    $registryKey = '_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments));
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

you can see Magento **checks** is something is already set in the registry before setting it.  The registry is a simple key/value store.

Fore some reason this "check if it's already set" code is failing/not-existing in your specific installation.  You'll need to debug why.